# How to reverse a game and inject a dll in client program?

Tags: ollydbg, c++, x64dbg, game-hacking, injection

I am trying to make a bot for a game. But when I open the game in debugger like Ollydbg or in x64dbg the game simply closes and also it doesn't appears in the *Attach to the process* list in File menu of debugger.

I have a source code for a client that if is not the same is almost the same. Can it help?

And if you guys can tell me steps to create a dll to inject on the client it would be awesome.

https://joguewydbr.com/WYDBR2022.msi - this is the application I want to reverse.

***Note***: Link will start download immediately. If you don't want to download the file, Please do not click.

Comment: Warning: link goes directly to the MSI itself so will start downloading when you click it.

Comment: Ty, I edited the questio with the warning

Comment: Debug protection?

Comment: For what I could get from the open soucer client is just a if the program is open or not it closes

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this will help or not. I had a similar situation for an android game which killed it self the moment it detected debuggers. What I did was, catch syscall `kill()` and find the instruction which caused it and then changed the condition that caused the call to `kill()` function. You could do a similar approach but when doing that I used `gdb`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a source code for a client

o_O where my sources, dude?

> the game simply closes

try to use ScyllaHide. [How to hide Remote Windows Debugger in IDA Pro?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31049/how-to-hide-remote-windows-debugger-in-ida-pro)

> steps to create a dll to inject

https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/grand-theft-auto-v/209725-easiest-inject-dll-files.html

https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c-/345937-injection-executable-code.html

https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/team-fortress-2-a/74219-noob-question-inject-code.html