# How to hide Remote Windows Debugger in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, debugging

Whenever I try to debug a 3D game through **VMware and IDA Pro**, an "access violation" pops up.
The error occurs in the body of the program after memory is allocated by the **operator New**.

- Memory is allocated
- pointer is not null

but, when trying to write to the allocated memory, an error occurs.

If I try to debug the program in **x64dbg** and turn on the "hide debugger" option, this problem does not arise.
However, it is inconvenient to work through this debugger, because I'm debugging a game that only runs in full screen.

so, how to hide **Remote Windows Debugger** in IDA Pro?

Comment: There are multiple ways to detect attached debuggers, so I don't think there is a general way. Make yourself familiar with the different anti-debugger techniques and then decompile that app and try to identify if each measure is present or not and what needs to be modified to bypass the anti-debugger measure.

Answer (score 3):

I already found a solution to my problem:
plugin for IDA Pro: [ScyllaHide](https://bitbucket.org/NtQuery/scyllahide/) ([active fork](https://github.com/x64dbg/ScyllaHide))